Remove duplicates from a multidimensional array based on certain keys
This is not about removing duplicates from an array but about removing a partial or fuzzy duplicate. Please read below for the solution I've come up with. I'm posting this as I'd like to think there's a better way to do it and I hope you can tell me what that is.
I have a page where the user can select service types, units, and corresponding rates (e.g. "translation", "per word", "0.05"). The problem is I can't prevent the user from adding the same "service type – unit" pair but with a different rate. So, I've decided I should purge any such "duplicates" from the $_POST array. Here is an example of an array that contains a "repeated" pair – the fifth subarray:
$rates = array(
    array("serviceType" => 1, "unit" => "word", "unitRate" => "0.05000"),
    array("serviceType" => 2, "unit" => "word", "unitRate" => "0.02500"),
    array("serviceType" => 3, "unit" => "hour", "unitRate" => "15.0000"),
    array("serviceType" => 4, "unit" => "hour", "unitRate" => "15.0000"),
    array("serviceType" => 5, "unit" => "hour", "unitRate" => "25.0000"),
    >>> array("serviceType" => 1, "unit" => "word", "unitRate" => "0.04000"),
    array("serviceType" => 6, "unit" => "minute", "unitRate" => "7.0000"),
    array("serviceType" => 7, "unit" => "minute", "unitRate" => "1.5000"),
    array("serviceType" => 8, "unit" => "minute", "unitRate" => "0.28330")
);

So, I first make a copy of this array:
$rates_purged = $rates;

Then, I remove the unitRate key and value to be able to apply array_unique.
for($i = 0; $i < count($rates); $i++) {
    $unitRates[] = $rates[$i]['unitRate'];
    unset($rates[$i]['unitRate']);
}

Now, remove any duplicates:
$ratesUnique = array_unique($rates, SORT_REGULAR);

Find the difference between the new ($ratesUnique) and the old ($rates) arrays, i.e. what has been removed:
$diff = array_diff_key($rates, $ratesUnique);

Get the array key of the removed subarray and assign it to a variable. I tried using array_column here to avoid the foreach loop but got a "conversion of array into string" error.
foreach(array_keys($diff) as $key) {
    $remove = $key;
}

Use the $remove variable to remove the corresponding sub-array from the unpurged array.
unset($rates_purged[$remove]);

Is there a better way to accomplish the same? Please let me know.

If the code posted is having no problems or issues then your question is more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

OK. I have never posted there. I thought that forum was intended for improving an existing solution, not for asking for an alternative (better) solution.

Isn't asking for a better solution, improving upon it?

@DarkBee, I suppose that depends on your point of view... To me, these are two separate solutions.

How about this? https://3v4l.org/ECEmU We combine serviceType and unit to one "key", and check if that is already contained in our helper array. If not - the current rate gets added to the result.

@CBroe, sure, as long as it achieves the same effect and requires less code than my attempt.

In cases where a row's "uniqueness" is determined by the value of more than one key (or in your case, all key values except one), I tend to just merge all the required key values together and let PHP take care of the deduplication:
foreach($rates as $rate){
    $deduplicated_rates[$rate['serviceType'].$rate['unit']] = $rate;
}
$rates = array_values($deduplicated_rates);

Note that where there are duplicate values, only the last value will be stored. If you want to return the first value instead, you can check if the key has already been set before adding a value to the deduplicated array:
foreach($rates as $rate){
    $key = $rate['serviceType'].$rate['unit'];
    $deduplicated_rates[$key] = $deduplicated_rates[$key] ?: $rate;
}
$rates = array_values($deduplicated_rates);

There is no* max key length of array keys. Go wild!
https://3v4l.org/R4qpk

Wow! Yes, that's the "one liner" I thought must exist. Thanks!

@cheeseus that one leaves the entry with 0.04000 though. If it doesn't matter to you, which of the duplicates you keep, that's fine. If not, you can check if $deduplicated_rates[$rate['serviceType'].$rate['unit']] is already set first, and only add the entry if that wasn't the case.

@CBroe, I guess I'm not doing this the correct way because if(isset($deduplicated_rates[$rate['serviceType'].$rate['unit']]) {   continue;  }  else {   $deduplicated_rates[$rate['serviceType'].$rate['unit']] = $rate;  } still returns the sub-array with 0.04000.

You're if statement is missing a closing ), so this should only get you a parse error. https://3v4l.org/Df5mY - or directly with the negated condition, https://3v4l.org/mroQX

@CBroe, oops. Yes, you're right. Fixed it and got the first result. Thanks! (But it's weird that PHP didn't throw an error about the missing bracket – I'm on a local server (WAMP) with PHP 8.3.4).

I added to my answer to include cases where you'd want to keep the first duplicate value, not the last.
